# Use monotone convergence theorem to show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not summable on $(0,1)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Use monotone convergence theorem to show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not summable on $(0,1)$.

The hint was to consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\max \{n, f(x)\}$, $x\in(0,1)$. It is clear that $0\le f_1 \le f_2 ,\ldots $ and each $f_1, f_2,\ldots $ is measurable.

But I have no idea at all how can I proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read again the hint. It must be $f_n(x)=\min\{n,f(x)\}$. For such $f_n$, to calculate $\int_{(0,1)}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, divide the interval $(0,1)$ in $(0,1/n)$ and $[1/n,1)$.

Comment: So there was error in the book... There is clearly written "max"

Comment: If you sketch graphs for $n=1,2,3$, you will note that $\max\{n,f(x)\}$ isn't an increasing sequence.

Comment: Ok I see this now... Thanks

Comment: How can I conclude that $f$ is not summable?

Comment: Note that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ puntually and $0\le f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. Then, by MCT, $f$ is measurable and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{(0,1)}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{(0,1)}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. Then, you must calculate $\int_{(0,1)}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, and my hint is that descompose the integral in $\int_{(0,1/n)}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{[1/n,1)}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Ok i got it now, thank you a lot. I see how I can show that $\int f = \infty$